# How to display an image inside an ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using ng-grid to create a table in which one of the columns is an image column. Each image cell will get it's image from ng-src. At the end of the URL, there will be a specific identifier. Here is the part of the directive for the cell template that sets the text of the image.  The 'image caption' is not appearing. Just getting `row.getProperty('imageCaption')`.

```
attrs.$set('ngSrc',
            "http://dummyimage.com/60x40/FFF/000&text=row.getProperty('imageCaption')");
```

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/M7Kt60MSRIQIGdvMNzAU?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you should need a directive here, you can set your ng-src inside your imagetemplate.html, like so:

```
<img ng-src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/FFF/000&text={{row.getProperty('imageCaption')}}" lazy-src >
```

Here is revised plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bh1LKHRUXHpJa4KEUtA7?p=preview

Comment: The purpose of the directive is to handle lazy loading of images. Basically, if the image is in the viewport(viewport-min.js), it makes the request. Else, it loads a placeholder image.  I also noticed that sorting fails when which is strange.

Comment: I'd give you +2 if I could, for introducing me to `lazy-src`. Not sure how I've gotten by without it.